# Remove all array elements that do not match specific condition

Tags: php, arrays

I've been looking into `array_map` but not sure if this is the best way to do it.

I am currently getting the following array returned from my `scandir`

```
Array ( [0] => . [1] => .. [2] => .DS_Store [3] => post-my-first-test-post.html [4] => post-my-second-test-post.html )
```

I want to remove all items in the array that do not match `"post-*` so it returns only an array of posts.

I have looked into using `glob` but not sure how to implement it with what I have.

Something like `glob("post-*");` ?

Comment: Did you check array_filter?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should be looking at [array_filter()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) instead

```
$result = array_filter(
    $originalArray,
    function($value) {
        return (strpos($value, 'post-') === 0);
    }
);
```

Though using [glob()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php) rather than scandir() would have allowed you to do the filter while actually retrieving the directory list

Comment: Doesn't glob bring back the entire path rather than just the filename?\

Comment: glob() only brings back the "matches" according to the examples in the php docs, so it depends on the actual glob expression that you use.... but you can then use [pathinfo()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.pathinfo.php) to extract only the filename if necessary